# Thermodynamics problem

Tags: thermodynamics

If water is heated between 273 K and 277 K by providing it heat, a part of heat is used to increase the internal energy of water and rest is done as work. But water's volume ***decreases*** between the given range due to anomalous behaviour of water. So, My question is **whether work is done by the system (+ve) or done on the system (-ve)** , If I define the system as a vessel containing water.

Comment: Also if **work is performed** , isn't it a contradiction after it is known that volume is **decreased** (for specific case of water under the given range of temperature).

Comment: Where's the contradiction? If, to draw an anlogy, we compress a gas its volume decreases, yet the work done on the gas is positive: $-\int pdV$.

Answer (score 0):

At normal atmospheric pressure water is ice at 273 K (-0.15 Celsius). Applying heat causes the ice to melt isothermally (at 273 K) and the Latent Heat of Fusion (of ice) has to be applied to cause that state transition to happen. Once melted, more heat then has to be applied to heat the water from 273 K to 277 K, taking into account the Heat Capacity of water.

It's true that during melting a small volume contraction, say $\Delta V$ occurs and during heating from 273 to 277 K a small volume expansion (say $\Delta V'$) takes place, so that in theory some work $p(\Delta V - \Delta V')$ is performed. However, due to the small temperature interval (273 to 277 K) this term is likely to be very small compared to the internal energy increase caused by melting and heating to 277 K.

Comment: But water's volume decreases between the given range due to abnormal behaviour of water.